# Returning object by value and stacksize limit

Tags: c++

As I understand, in modern C++ it is recommended to return objects by value on the stack compared to allocating memory on the heap with e.g. `make_unique<>()` and return a `unique_ptr`. The compiler will ensure that no copying of the returned object-value happens. So it is recommended to trust the compiler to optimize the return details for return-by-value.

However, if we are to follow this advice even for large objects a stack overflow could in theory happen, right? I tested this on my Linux laptop:

```
#include <iostream>
// Allocate 40 MB (10,000,000 x 4)
#define ASIZE 10000000

struct Foo {
    int a[ASIZE]; // Note: On my Linux laptop, sizeof(int) == 4
};

Foo get_foo() {
    Foo a_foo;
    a_foo.a[1] = 2;
    return a_foo;
}

int main() {
    Foo myfoo = get_foo();
    std::cout << "sizeof(a) = " << sizeof(struct Foo) << "\n";
    std::cout << "foo1 = " << myfoo.a[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This program aborts with a segmentation fault if `ASIZE` == 10,000,000, but works fine if 
`ASIZE` == 1,000,000.

(I hoped for a more descriptive error message like `Stackoverflow! Abort` or something :)). 
Anyway, how does this relate to the advice of returning values on the stack? Does it only apply if the size of the objects are small? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The general advice was and still is that large objects should be dynamically allocated and you should hold a pointer to them.

Comment: The real advice is: always pick a correct tool for the job. And the rule of thumb is: put small objects on stack, large on heap. And for every rule there are exceptions. Finally: is this really an issue with returning a value or simply with allocating it? I fail to see how this is related to returning, considering RVO.

Comment: `std::vector<int> a(ASIZE);` now your underlying memory is heap allocated, but you still have RAII, copy elision where applicable, return value optimization, etc.

Comment: C++ was founded on the principle that you don't pay for what you don't use. The vast majority of times, 100% of the time in a correct program, the stack is not overflowed, making a check for stack overflow an unnecessary price. Some systems in "debug mode" do make checks like this to help while developing the software, but it can't be counted on.

Comment: It's not a good idea to allocate large objects on the stack, but if you do with NVRO/RVO there is no doubling of stack usage when returning a large object from a function. It exists only in the stack space of the calling function. It has to have enough room in the calling function and the called function is not affected by the returned object's size.

Answer (score 1):

You can always start with a stack-based container, but prefer [std::array or stack_array for arrays on the stack](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-stack) to avoid the pitfalls of arrays being treated as pointers. Normally a single array holding all data might mean that there is a data design problem, so I'd first think about that before switching to heap objects without second thoughts.

If stack size is really the issue, you can use the standard library heap-based containers (e.g. `vector`, `list`, etc.). Those solve the stack overflow issue and support move semantics, so using references and copying by value should still be preferred over using smart pointers.